# Conditional sentences.

Tags: conditional-constructions

**"If you will only help me in the kitchen, I would cook your favorite meal tomorrow."**

**'if you help me in the kitchen, I will cook your favorite meal tomorrow."**

**"If you helped me in the kitchen, I would cook your favorite meal tomorrow."**

What're the differences between these three sentences meaning wise?

And, I came across the original sentence here:

https://www.grammarly.com/handbook/sentences/conditional-sentences/9/conditional-sentences-if-clause-future-tense-resul/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your sentences talk about a trade off of help for a nice meal

> If you will only help me in the kitchen, I would cook your favorite meal tomorrow.

from the use of "*will only*" it sounds like *someone* is exasperated and pleading for help
in the kitchen

> if you help me in the kitchen, I will cook your favorite meal tomorrow.

sounds like a normal request for help, bargaining help for a nice meal

> If you helped me in the kitchen, I would *(have)* cooked your favorite meal tomorrow.

sounds like *someone* explaining why the lack of help will result in a nonfavorite meal tomorrow.